# How can I best assert a value can be converted to int in Python?

Tags: python, testing, assertions

I'm writing some tests in Python and for one of the tests I need to verify that a value either is an int or can be converted to an int cleanly.

Should pass:

```
0
1
"0"
"123456"
```

Should fail:

```
""
"x"
"1.23"
3.14
```

How can I best write this assertion?

Answer (score 5):

So, to be 100% sure, it must be something like:

```
def is_integery(val):
    if isinstance(val, (int, long)):  # actually integer values
        return True
    elif isinstance(val, float):  # some floats can be converted without loss
        return int(val) == float(val)
    elif not isinstance(val, basestring):  # we can't convert non-string
        return False
    else:    
        try:  # try/except is better then isdigit, because "-1".isdigit() - False
            int(val)
        except ValueError:
            return False  # someting non-convertible

        return True
```

In answers below thre is a check, using type conversions and equality checking, but I think it will not work correctly for huge integers.

Maybe there is shorter way

Comment: @Schoolboy In question: "How can I best write this assertion?"

Comment: @soon int("3.14") will raise exception

Comment: It will, but I told about `3.14`, not `"3.14"`. Look at the last line in the second block(fails) in the question.

Comment: @soon you right. Missed it. Re-wrote code to handle all conditions

Comment: A float literal can be converted to an int without error, but a float containing a whole number should pass this test.

Comment: @sr2222 it wouldn't pass type checks, it's not int/long and not basestring

Comment: Yet `3.0` should pass the check.  Also, you've given up on duck typing pretty much completely here.

Comment: @sr2222 oh, yes. Added this case check

Comment: And now `Decimal` type values?  It doesn't matter how many type special cases you add, there will always be more.

Comment: @sr2222 I'm not sure, that author need to cover literally all types.

Comment: The point is that trying to do things like this with type checking in a duck-typed language like Python will only lead to heartbreak.

Comment: You need to decide, what is possible scope of input data, and then base your solution on this.

Comment: You don't always have that kind of control, and your users aren't always going to be fully aware.  Normalizing data in a dynamic duck-typed language is very difficult, and as soon as you try to do it by restricting types for the normalization process, you start to break encapsulation.

Answer (score 3):

use the isnumeric() function like:

```
>>> test = "X"
>>> test = str(test)
>>> test.isnumeric()
False
```

Try/ Except works. But I do not think it is a good idea. Try/ Except should be used for expectable errors, not for other specific purpose/function.

Update: if you want to take the negative integer be true:

```
>>> def is_int(test):
        test = str(test)
        if len(test) != 0 and test[0] == "-":
            test = test[1:]
        return test.isnumeric()
>>> is_int(124)
True
>>> is_int(12.4)
False
>>> is_int("")
False
>>> is_int("X")
False
>>> is_int("123")
True
```

PS: I am not sure about the "can be converted to an int cleanly". If this is means the 1.0000 should pass, the following code should work:

```
>>> test = 3.14
>>> test = str(test)
>>> pattern = "[+-]?[0-9]+(\.)?(0)*\Z"
>>> re.match(pattern, test) != None
```

Comment: This won't fail for floating point values, and does an extraneous type conversion.

Comment: @sr2222 It works for float valuse, with my Python3. I did not test it on Python2.

Comment: Will fail for floats.. `"."` is not numeric, also fails for `"-10"`, `'-'` is not numeric...

Comment: @Schoolboy Yes. Thanks to your comment, I noticed this issue and fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a try/except block for type conversion problems, then an equality check for non-integer values.

```
def is_int(val):
    try:
        int_ = int(val)
        float_ = float(val)
    except:
        return False
    if int_ == float_:
        return True
    else:
        return float_ / int(float_) == 1
```

Comment: This will generally work, although you'll run into potential issues if using huge integers that can't be accurately represented in floating point.

Comment: @sr2222 it will fail for really long integers, because float will lost precision. long(float(1000000000000000000000000000)) = 1000000000000000013287555072L

Comment: Yeah, I know.  I was trying to think of something that didn't involve string conversion, but at least for the huge integer case, I can't think of anything that would work.

Comment: @sr2222 I can be wrong, but string conversions wouldn't work in some cases, so actually, I don't know an answer that will work for any type.

Comment: Honestly, the best test I can think of that would actually work would be to just check for the presence of a decimal separator with non-zeros after it in the string.

Comment: @Amber, yeah, probably.  You can't avoid all loss of precision, but conversion to a string (provided you take care to convert with maximum precision for each type) is probably the most reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
def is_int(x):
    try:
        return int(x) == float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: You already fixed it. Before edition you just check with `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def isInt(v):
...     assert str(v).isdigit()

>>> isInt(1)
>>> isInt(3.14)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 2, in isInt
AssertionError
>>> isInt('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 2, in isInt
AssertionError
>>>
```

Comment: This is good, though the edge case of a string with a decimal point with no value or all 0s following it could be a problem, depending upon the specific requirements.  "1.0000" and "1." can be cleanly converted to an int, but they would fail your test.

Comment: Ah, I missed the '...or can be converted to an int cleanly' clause there.

Comment: Also, as @schoolboy points out in Sheng's answer's comments, it's going to have problems with negative numbers as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to specify exactly what string formats for integers you're willing to accept. E.g.

```
re.match(r"\d+\.?0*", string)
```

will match any string that has at least one digit, optionally followed by a decimal point and some zeroes.

Comment: Include an optional sign character (+/-) at the front, and this would probably actually be the best answer.  Or at least the most concise.

Comment: @sr2222 Actually it will fail for "3.00abc". See the update part of my answer.

Comment: It actually will match for "3.00abc". `re.match` matches from the beginning of the string; it doesn't have to be an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly shorter solution:

```
def is_mostly_int(val):
    try:
        return str(int(val)) == str(val)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return False
```

It won't accept things like "1E10" or "1.00000", though.